# Compiling multiple files using CL

Tags: c, windows, makefile, nmake, cl

How would this GNU makefile look for windows (I must use nmake and CL):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g

build: main

main: utils.o bucket.o hashset.o main.o

utils.o: utils.c utils.h

bucket.o: bucket.c bucket.h

hashset.o: hashset.c hashset.h

main.o: main.c

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ main
```

All I could come up with was this:

```
CPP = cl
CFLAGS   = /nologo /W4 /EHsc /Za

build : main

main: utils.obj bucket.obj hashset.obj main.obj
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) /Fe$@ $**

utils.obj: utils.c
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $**

bucket.obj: bucket.c
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $**

hashset.obj: hashset.c
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $**

main.obj: main.c
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) /Fo$@ $**

clean:
    del *.obj main
```

Note that my homework was implementing a hashset, which I have done, it's just the makefile that troubles me for now.
I keep getting errors for every file: unexpected end of file

Comment: What does the error say? (The error, the whole error, and nothing but the error)

Comment: fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 Ultimate 2013\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.

Comment: Have you tried pressing ENTER after the last line in your Makefile?

Comment: Having a newline at the end of the makefile did not help

Comment: I also get this warning:
    F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 Ultimate 2013\VC\INCLUDE\sal.h(156
) : warning C4001: nonstandard extension 'single line comment' was used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping, in the meanwhile I figured out the answer myself:

```
CPP = cl
OBJ_LIST = main.obj utils.obj bucket.obj hashset.obj

build: main

main: $(OBJ_LIST)
    $(CPP) /Fe$@ $**

clean:
    del *.obj main.exe
```

Comment: It should be `main.exe` wherever main is.

Answer (score 0):

C1004 is a compiler error. Try to localize which particular compiler invocation causes it. In any case, `$**` doesn't look right. Instead, for the `.obj` rules use `$<`, and `$^` for a link rule.